# Linq query with c#

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2005

I have two tables categories and products, and I have to create a linq query that returns me the first 2 lines of products in each category.

Thanks for the help

```
var res = from prod in context.Prodotti
          join cat in context.Categorie on coup.id_categoria  equals cat.id_categoria
          select coup;
```

Comment: Have you tried to use: `Take(2)`? Show us your code...

Comment: Where are your attempts?

Comment: Sounds like homework..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something like the following works:

```
var query = context.Categorie
    .Join(context.Prodotti,
        cat  => cat.id_categoria,
        prod => prod.id_categoria,
        (cat, prod) => new { prod, cat })
    .GroupBy(x => x.cat.id_categoria)
    .Select(catGroup => catGroup.Select(x => x.prod).Take(2));
```

This returns the first two products of each category-group. So you get an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Prodotti>>`. Here the query syntax which i prefer with `join`:

```
var query = from cat in context.Categorie
            join prod in context.Prodotti 
            on cat.id_categoria equals prod.id_categoria 
            select new { cat, prod } into x
            group x by x.cat.id_categoria into catGroup
            select catGroup.Select(x => x.prod).Take(2);
```

Comment: The first result is not IEnumerable<Prodotti>

Comment: @AntonioDiGirolamo: i don't understand your comment. Yes, it is `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Prodotti>>`.

Comment: The result of the query is IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Categorie>>

Comment: @AntonioDiGirolamo: have a look at my edit. The order was wrong, so `(cat, prod)` instead of `(prod, cat)`. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29823446/revisions

Comment: @AntonioDiGirolamo: that flattens all grouped into a single list. Ok, if that's what you want :)